# string sent to a webmethod with json/ajax

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i have a ajax call sending some data to a webmethod (c#) from a aspx page and one of the parameters sent is some free text comments. now i have noticed some errors and the updates dont get made to the database. So with some checking out i believe its slashes and 's and probably other characters doing causing this. i tried using escape() method and it works, but then adds all sorts of encoded text to the database which i dont want. Im not a greatly experienced coder so i know there is some sort of encoding to do here, but how im not sure. here is the ajax below that works until i get slashes and

```
$("#btnEditFields").click(function () {
    //Store the New comment
    var strSupplierOrderNo = $("#<%=tbPopUpEditSuppOrdNo.ClientID%>").val();
    var strComment = $("#<%=tbPopUpEditComments.ClientID%>").val();
    var strCurrentStage = $("#<%=ddlPopUpEditCurrentStage.ClientID%>").val();
    var strReviewDate = $("#<%=tbPopUpEditReviewDate.ClientID%>").val();
    var strOrderDate = $("#<%=tbPopUpEditOrderDate.ClientID%>").val();
    var strRequiredLive = $("#<%=tbPopUpEditRequiredLiveDate.ClientID%>").val();
    var strActualAppointmentDate = $("#<%=tbPopUpEditActualAppointmentDate.ClientID%>").val();
    var strOtherRef = $("#<%=tbPopUpFieldOtherRef.ClientID%>").val();
    var EditRecordArgs = (strServiceID + "," + strSupplierOrderNo + "," + strComment + "," + strCurrentStage + "," + strReviewDate + "," + strOrderDate + "," + strRequiredLive + "," + strActualAppointmentDate + "," + strOtherRef);
    //alert(addNewCommentArgs);
    // Confirming the operation from the user
    if (confirm("You are about to add a new comment to order " + strPSTNNum + "?")) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            //UpdateRecordInGridViewUsingAjax.aspx is the page name and UpdateOrder 
            // is the server side web method which actually does the updation
            url: "PSTN_OrderManagementTracker.aspx/updatePSTNDataInDB",
            //Passing the record id and data to be updated which is in the variable update_data
            data: "{'args': '" + EditRecordArgs + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            //Giving message to user on successful updation
            success: function () {
                alert("Comment successfully added!!!");
                location.reload(); 
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert(thrownError);
        }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
});
```

Here Is the web method:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void updatePSTNDataInDB(string args)
{
    string[] data = args.Trim().Split(',');
    string strServiceID = data[0];
    string strSupplierOrderNo = data[1];
    string strComment = data[2];
    string strCurrentStage = data[3];
    string strReviewDate = data[4];
    string strOrderDate = data[5];
    string strRequiredLive = data[6];
    string strActualAppointmentDate = data[7];            
    string strOtherRef = data[8];            
    #region Check for and existing PSTNReport Record and create one if not, then run the update to the database.
    SqlConnection seConnection1 = new SqlConnection();
    seConnection1.ConnectionString = Databases.getDbConnectionString("csSingleEnded2");
    seConnection1.Open();
    SqlCommand seCmd1 = new SqlCommand("CheckForPSTNReportRecord", seConnection1);
    seCmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    seCmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ServiceID", SqlDbType.Int));
    seCmd1.Parameters["@ServiceID"].Value = strServiceID;
    SqlDataAdapter dbAdapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter(seCmd1);
    DataSet dbSeDataset1 = new DataSet();
    dbAdapter1.Fill(dbSeDataset1);
    if (dbSeDataset1.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        SqlCommand seCmd2 = new SqlCommand("AddAPSTNReportRecord", seConnection1);
        //specify that the command is a sproc and not just SQL text
        seCmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        //Create the parameters
        seCmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ServiceID", SqlDbType.Int));
        seCmd2.Parameters["@ServiceID"].Value = strServiceID;
        SqlDataAdapter dbAdapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter(seCmd2);
        DataSet dbSeDataset2 = new DataSet();
        dbAdapter2.Fill(dbSeDataset2);
        seConnection1.Close();
    }
    SqlConnection seConnection = new SqlConnection();
    seConnection.ConnectionString = Databases.getDbConnectionString("csSingleEnded2");
    seConnection.Open();
    SqlCommand seCmd = new SqlCommand("UpdatePstnOrdersComments", seConnection);
    seCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    seCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ServiceID", SqlDbType.Int));
    seCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SupplierOrderNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar,50));
    seCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Comments", SqlDbType.NVarChar,4000));
    seCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@OrderDate", SqlDbType.DateTime));
    seCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RequiredLiveDate", SqlDbType.DateTime));
    seCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AppointmentDate", SqlDbType.DateTime));
    seCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ReviewDate", SqlDbType.DateTime));
    seCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CurrentStage", SqlDbType.NVarChar,500));
    seCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@OtherRef", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 500));
    seCmd.Parameters["@ServiceID"].Value = strServiceID;
    seCmd.Parameters["@SupplierOrderNumber"].Value = strSupplierOrderNo;
    seCmd.Parameters["@Comments"].Value = strComment ;
    seCmd.Parameters["@OrderDate"].Value = strOrderDate;
    seCmd.Parameters["@RequiredLiveDate"].Value = strRequiredLive;
    seCmd.Parameters["@AppointmentDate"].Value = strActualAppointmentDate;
    seCmd.Parameters["@ReviewDate"].Value = strReviewDate;
    seCmd.Parameters["@CurrentStage"].Value = strCurrentStage;
    seCmd.Parameters["@OtherRef"].Value = strOtherRef;
    SqlDataAdapter dbAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(seCmd);
    DataSet dbSeDataset = new DataSet();
    dbAdapter.Fill(dbSeDataset);
    seConnection.Close();
}
```

just for completion i have put an error from firebug when i try to add an apostrophe in the middle of a wrod:

> "Invalid object passed in, ':' or '}' expected. (50): {'args':
>   '158581,aaa5-5-23264304431
>   ,aaaaaCustom'er%20still%20not%20ready%20as%20civils%20work%20has%20still%20not%20been%20completed%20%26%20currently%20there%20still%20hasn%27t%20been%20any%20duct/cable/dp%20installed%2C%20as%20confirmed%20with%20the%20site%20contact%20Steve%20Williams%20who%20was%20unaware%20of%20this%20appointment.%20Also%20this%20quoted%20dp%20will%20be%20the%20incorrect%20dp%20as%20the%20address%20for%20the%20dp%20is%20an%20ext%u2019l%20block%20at%2015%20Seel%20street%20%26%20the%20premier%20inn%20is%20a%20brand%20new%20hotel%20just%20being%20completed.%0A%20Also%20rang%20the%20project%20team%20to%20inform%20them%20of%20the%20reasons%20for%20the%20delay.%0A%0ASMCYB07%2027/09/2012%2014%3A50%3A00%0A,Civils,22/05/2013,22/05/2013,22/05/2013,22/05/2013,aaaa'}"
>      StackTrace     " at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeDictionary(Int32
>   depth) at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32
>   depth) at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String
>   input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer) at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer
>   serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit) at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String
>   input) at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParamsFromPostRequest(HttpContext
>   context, JavaScriptSerializer serializer) at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData
>   methodData, HttpContext context) at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext
>   context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)"     ExceptionType
>     "System.ArgumentException"

Comment: Based on the description it sounds like the server-side code (not shown in the question at this time) has a SQL injection vulnerability, which is a very bad thing.  How are you writing to the database?  You may not need to add all sorts of encodings, but you do need to properly "escape" the input to the database so it knows what's text and what's control characters.

Comment: i have added the webmethod also thanks David

Comment: What's the error you're seeing and where does it happen?  It appears that the code is calling stored procedures, so there's a possibility that the problem is in the stored procedure code.  Can you do some debugging and narrow down more specifically when the problem happens and what the runtime values are?

Comment: the error is not with the webmethod as everything works ok when there are not slashes or Apostrophes, using firebug i get the error with the json and it does not get as far as the web method

Answer (score 0):

Use System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode() to decode the comment.

```
seCmd.Parameters["@Comments"].Value = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(strComment);
```

Comment: Hi the problem was definitely with the apostrophes and the JSON as if i added an apostrophe to the comment, it failed. anyway i tried using strComment = encodeURIComponent(strComment); which appears to replace certain characters, however on the return from the database i used: Label lblComments = new Label();
lblComments = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblComments");
string strComments = lblComments.Text;
strComments = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(strComments);
lblComments.Text = strComments;
This does not seem to remove the encoded stuff and leaves encoded chars

Answer (score 0):

You can use encodeURI(http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp) or encodeURIComponent(http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp)  on client side and Url.Unescape(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.unescape.aspx) on server side.

and instead of `data: "{'args': '" + EditRecordArgs + "'}"` as my mind better to use

```
data: "{'arg1': '" + arg1Value + "', arg2': '"+ arg2Value ...+" }"
```

for avoid problems with `Trim`

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest instead of passing values comma seperated use json objects. It will be more clear and you can pass values easily.

Make a JS class

```
EditRecordArgs = {};
EditRecordArgs.ServiceID = '“' + strServiceID+ '”'; 
EditRecordArgs.SupplierNo = '“' + strSupplierOrderNo + '”'; 
EditRecordArgs.Comment = '“' + strComment + '”';
```

.

..

....

Make a class in C#

```
Public ServiceRecord
{
public string  ServiceID{get; set;}
public string  SupplierNo{get; set;}
public string  Comment{get; set;}
}
```

In a class

use namespace

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

In a web Method

```
ServiceRecord r = ser.Deserialize<ServiceRecord>(args);
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON string to send data to server and deserialize data back from server.

```
$("#btnEditFields").click(function () {
        //Store the New comment
       var data = {};
    data.strSupplierOrderNo =$("#<%=tbPopUpEditSuppOrdNo.ClientID%>").val();
    data.strComment =$("#<%=tbPopUpEditComments.ClientID%>").val();;
    .
    .
    .
    ...
        // Confirming the operation from the user
        if (confirm("You are about to add a new comment to order " + strPSTNNum + "?")) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                //UpdateRecordInGridViewUsingAjax.aspx is the page name and UpdateOrder 
                // is the server side web method which actually does the updation
                url: "PSTN_OrderManagementTracker.aspx/updatePSTNDataInDB",
                //Passing the record id and data to be updated which is in the variable update_data
                data: {args: JSON.stringify(data)},
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                //Giving message to user on successful updation
                success: function () {
                    alert("Comment successfully added!!!");
                    location.reload(); 
                },
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(thrownError);
            }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
    });
```

And the Code behind

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void updatePSTNDataInDB(string args)
{
  var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  Dictionary<string, string> jsonObjects = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(args);

  strSupplierOrderNo =  jsonObjects[strSupplierOrderNo];
}
```